# Nginx load balancer upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have two servers - first is a load balancer nginx, second is an nginx + php-fpm app (at this moment third is inactive). Last time I noticed in logs of load balancer nginx the following error (and sometimes I get status code 500):

```
2024/01/29 23:07:09 [error] 1609602#1609602: *724 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xx.xx.xx, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /user?destination=node%252F1083276&redirect=1 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://xxx.xx.xx.xx/user?destination=node%252F1083276&redirect=1", host: "www.example.com"
```

I tried with increasing different timeouts, changing `proxy_buffer_size` and adding       `proxy_read_timeout 300;` and `proxy_connect_timeout 300;` but nothing helps.
Below is my configuration of load balancer nginx after my increase timeouts.

```
upstream apps {
    server app1;

}

server {
...
    proxy_connect_timeout  600s;
    proxy_send_timeout  600s;
    proxy_read_timeout  600s;

    proxy_buffer_size   1024k; 
    proxy_buffers    4 1024k; 
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   1024k;

    location / {
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass https://apps;
      proxy_request_buffering off;
      proxy_read_timeout 300;
      proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    }


}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.com www.example.com;
   
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

What else can I change or check?